# How to point a Wordpress registered domain to github pages?

Tags: domain-name-system, wordpress, github

I'm trying to use a CNAME file in my git hub project to point to my wordpress registered domain name. E.g. `example.com` to point to `myusername.github.com`.

I read [Github-Setting up a custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages) and it tells me to point the domain to their servers:

> *For a TLD like example.com, you should use an A record pointing to 204.232.175.78:*

But in the wordpress domain manager I only get the option to specify a nameserver like this:

`NS1.WORDPRESS.COM NS2.WORDPRESS.COM`

Inputting `204.232.175.78` in the wordpress manager give me an "invalid TLD." What am I doing wrong and how can I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nameservers and DNS are different things. Github has asked you to setup the *DNS*, Wordpress is asking you to setup *nameservers*.

Their relationship is that the nameservers (e.g. `ns1.wordpress.com` and `ns2.wordpress.com`) specify where a client should go *to find the DNS records*

In this case, if Wordpress doesn't offer you DNS management, you should get a free one ([you can Google](http://google.com/search?q=free%20dns%20hosting) for this).

At that point, you setup that is called an `A Record` which points to `204.232.175.78`. So, it'll look something like this:

```
example.com. IN A 204.232.175.78
```

The final step would be to setup those nameservers that this free DNS hosting provider gives you, `ns1.free_dns_hosting.tld` and `ns1.free_dns_hosting.tld`. It might be worth spending a few minutes to check if Wordpress gives you DNS management or not, before starting this process.

Comment: For some reason I was confused with DNS/Nameservers. Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Comment: No problem. If you're happy with the answer, please press the green hollow tick on the left to accept it :-)

Comment: Ahh! Clicking on the green arrow marks it as answered. I apologize for the novice questions. Stack Exchange has been excellent in answering my questions that I have not had to make an account till now. I'd also give you an vote up but I need 10 rep points.

Comment: Indeed! No worries. You might like to have a browse over the FAQ for more, it's worth a read!